# Laravel file download

Tags: php, file, laravel, vue.js

I've got a method in my Laravel 5.3 application that returns a file like this:

```
public function show(File $file)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/' . $file->getPath());
    return response()->download($path, $file->name);
}
```

I'm making a get request in vue.js like this:

```
show (file) {
    Vue.http.get('/api/file/' + file);
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

What could be wrong here? I'm expecting that I the browser downloads the image.

--EDIT--

[image]

When I `dd($path);` this is the result: `/home/vagrant/Code/forum/storage/app/users/3/messages/xReamZk7vheAyNGkJ8qKgVVsrUbagCdeze.png`

The route is in my `api.php`:

```
Route::get('/file/{file}',                             'File\FileController@show');
```

When I add it to my web.php it's working. But I need to acces it through my api!

Comment: Add headers in `download()` method as 3rd argument

Comment: What kind of headers? I thought they where already included.

Comment: Can you show `dd($path)` in your question?

Comment: @Amit sure: ```"/home/vagrant/Code/forum/storage/app/users/3/messages/xReamZk7vheAyNGkJ8qKgVVsrUbagCdeze.png"```

Comment: I have a doubt that why you are type -hinting `File` in `public function show(File $file)`. I think by looking at your `route` file it should be a string as `public function show($file)`.

Comment: @Amit when I add it to ```web.php``` instead of ```api.php``` it's working! But  I need to acces it from my api.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public function show(File $file)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/' . $file->getPath());
    $headers = array(
      'Content-Type: image/png',
    );
    return response()->download($path, $file->name, $headers);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I still receive the same!

Answer (score 0):

Add headers :

```
public function show(File $file)
{
  $path = storage_path('app/' . $file->getPath());
  if(!file_exists($path)) throw new Exception("Can't get file");
  $headers = array(
    "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($path) . "\"",
    "Content-Type: application/force-download",
    "Content-Length: " . filesize($path),
    "Connection: close"
  );
  return response()->download($path, $file->name, $headers);
}
```

OR
use custom download function must be like this :

```
function download($filepath, $filename = '') {
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filepath) . "\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));
    header("Connection: close");
    readfile($filepath);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me. I've done that ^. When I look at the image in my network tab (see edit that I've made above) it's showing the headers. But it's not working :(

Comment: did you try to make my second option ? 
First i think you have to test file existence , are you sur the path is correct and image is accessible ?

Comment: When I add the route to ```web.php``` instead of ```api.php``` it's working but I need to acces it from my api.

Comment: you need to make a service from web and call it from api

Comment: When I do that it's not working in my vue.js application. But when I acces it through the browser it's working.

Comment: And I've to make an api request because I'm using JWT Auth.